# Jquery Mobile tabs in page content

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am searching a plugin in jQuery mobile for tab implementation. tabs must be in content of the page. This is wat I have...

```
<div data-role="page" id="nav">
  <div data-role="page" id="nav">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h3>
            Header
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">

        <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">

            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#one" data-theme="" data-icon="" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">
                        Button
                    </a>
                    </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-theme="" data-icon="">
                        Button
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-theme="" data-icon="">
                        Button
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-theme="" data-icon="">
                        Button
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-theme="" data-icon="">
                        Button
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="one" data-transition="slide">
            <div data-role="content" style="background-color:#ff0;">    
                <h1>One</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h3>
            Footer
        </h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

When i click on page id "one". it is not displaying its respective content.
Can anyone pls help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or you can use my tabview plugin. Based on JQM collapsbile set, you just need to replace JQMs collapsible and collapsible set widget with my versions. Old collapsibles will continue working as normal. When you add `data-type="horizontal"` to a collapsible set, it becomes ... tabs...

[Demo here](http://www.franckreich.de/jqm/tabview/demo.html), Repo on [Github](https://github.com/frequent/tabview).

[image: Tabview Demo]

I like the other solution, too.

Comment: then please mark my answer as the one that helped you, so others will see it too.

Answer (score 2):

I modified [jQuery.mobile-tabs](https://github.com/groovetrain/jQuery.mobile-Tabs) to allow the tab bar to be placed anywhere within the page. Is this what you had in mind?

[image: Tabs]

Comment: nice! Need to check this one out, too.